# Profiling a PostgreSQL function

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

if I use

```
explain (analyze true, verbose true, costs true, buffers true)
select * from mystoredprocedurefunction(arg1, arg2);
```

I do not get any information about what the server is actually doing inside my sp.  Instead I get 5 rows describing that I invoked a function and that it took a long time.  How do I look into my stored procedure and see what is going on?  I have something very inefficient occurring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into the module [`auto-explain`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auto-explain.html).

Very similar, recent question with answers:

- [Get query plan for SQL statement nested in a PL/pgSQL function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23355/get-a-query-plan-for-sql-statement-nested-in-a-pl-pgsql-function)