# How to log DML statements executed by a pl/pgsql function?

Tags: postgresql, functions, plpgsql, log, dml

I have a pl/pgsql function (see below) that lists some fields and clears their contents using dynamically constructed UPDATE commands.

When I set `log_statement = 'mod'`, I can see nothing on the log upon execution of the function with `SELECT fnct_clear_temp_fields();`.
When I set `log_statement = 'all'`, and execute the function I can see `SELECT fnct_clear_temp_fields();` in the log, but not the underlying UPDATE commands.

Is there a way to have the UPDATE commands appear in the log as well ?

For info, here is the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fnct_clear_temp_fields() RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE
    --Put into a cursor a view dynamically listing all user-defined fields beginning with 'temp_'
    dataset_1 CURSOR FOR 
        SELECT 
            column_name,
            table_name
        FROM information_schema.tables 
        NATURAL JOIN information_schema.columns 
        WHERE 
            table_schema='public'
            AND table_type='BASE TABLE'
            AND column_name ~ '^temp_'
        ORDER BY table_name,column_name;

    --Record variable to go through each line of the view above
    dataset_1_row RECORD;

BEGIN
    OPEN dataset_1; --Open the cursor
    FETCH dataset_1 INTO dataset_1_row; --first row of the view

    WHILE FOUND LOOP
        RAISE NOTICE 'Table: %, Column: %',  dataset_1_row.table_name,dataset_1_row.column_name;

        --Set to NULL the contents of the current 'temp_' column
        EXECUTE 'UPDATE '||dataset_1_row.table_name||' SET '||dataset_1_row.column_name||'=NULL WHERE '||dataset_1_row.column_name||' IS NOT NULL';

        FETCH dataset_1 INTO dataset_1_row; --next row please.
    END LOOP; --while end

    CLOSE dataset_1;

    RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: If you need it only in this function, you can `RAISE LOG '%', your_statement;`  Also, I find the `FOR dataset_1_row IN SELECT ... LOOP` construct much smoother.

Comment: Thanks for the tips dezso, well appreciated. The FOR ... LOOP is indeed a much better construction. About the `RAISE LOG '%',` I have put it directly in front of my `EXECUTE 'UPDATE'...` command, but it gives me: `ERROR:  type "execute" does not exist`.

Comment: PostgreSQL doesn't have built-in support for logging all DML run within functions. It'd be useful to have for a narrow subset of cases, but nobody's implemented it yet. The new `pgaudit` extension (in development for 9.5, may be usable with 9.4 too) should add this facility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, my suggestion as an actual answer:

If you need it only in this function, you can do a `RAISE LOG '%', your_statement;`, or in your actual code:

```
...
DECLARE
    exec_str text;
...
    --Set to NULL the contents of the current 'temp_' column
    exec_str := 'UPDATE '||dataset_1_row.table_name||
                'SET '||dataset_1_row.column_name||'=NULL 
                 WHERE '||dataset_1_row.column_name||' IS NOT NULL';
    RAISE LOG 'Query executed: %', exec_str;
    EXECUTE exec_str;
...
```

Also, I find the

```
FOR dataset_1_row IN SELECT ... 
LOOP 
END LOOP;
```

construct much smoother.

Answer (score 8):

#### Question asked

There **is** a built-in way to log statements inside PL/pgSQL functions: **[`auto-explain`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auto-explain.html)**

```
LOAD 'auto_explain';
SET auto_explain.log_min_duration = 1;  -- exclude very fast trivial queries
SET auto_explain.log_nested_statements = ON;  -- statements inside functions
```

See:

- [Get query plan for SQL statement nested in a PL/pgSQL function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23355/get-a-query-plan-for-sql-statement-nested-in-a-pl-pgsql-function)

Potentially generates *a lot* of log output. Only use it for debugging, not in production.
If you just need the one statement logged, go with [@dezso's advice](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/71202/3684).

### Code audit

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fnct_clear_temp_fields()
  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
DECLARE
   rec record;
   qry text;
BEGIN
   FOR rec IN
      SELECT quote_ident(c.relname) AS tbl, quote_ident(a.attname) AS col
      FROM   pg_namespace n
      JOIN   pg_class     c ON c.relnamespace = n.oid
      JOIN   pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = c.oid
      WHERE  n.nspname = 'public'
      AND    c.relkind = 'r'
      AND    a.attname LIKE 'temp_%'  -- LIKE is faster than ~
      AND    a.attnum > 0
      AND    NOT a.attisdropped
      ORDER  BY 1,2
   LOOP

      RAISE NOTICE 'Table: %, Column: %', rec.tbl, rec.col;
      qry := format('UPDATE %1$s SET %2$s = NULL WHERE %2$s IS NOT NULL', rec.tbl, rec.col);
      RAISE LOG 'Query: %', qry;
      EXECUTE qry;

   END LOOP;
END
$func$;
```

You **must** sanitize all identifiers concatenated into dynamic SQL, else it can fail with non-standard names that require double-quoting. Worse, you are open to SQL injection.
Demonstrating [`quote_ident()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER), since you are using the sanitized identifiers multiple times. There are more options with `regclass` or [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER):

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10711349/939860)

I prefer to base such queries on the system catalog instead of the sometimes slow and convoluted views of the information schema. A question of requirements and personal preference. Demonstrating the equivalent, which is ~ 10 times faster (not regarding `UPDATE` commands). See:

- [How to check if a table exists in a given schema](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24089729/939860)

`LIKE` is generally faster than the more powerful regular expression matching (`~`). If `LIKE` can do the job, use it.

Related answer with more details:

- [Update record of a cursor where the table name is a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18833367/939860)

Answer (score 1):

Great dezso, it works!
Here is the final version of my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fnct_clear_temp_fields() RETURNS VOID AS $$
DECLARE
    dataset_1_row RECORD; --Record variable to go through each row of the view below
    update_query TEXT; --The dynamic UPDATE query to be executed

BEGIN
    FOR dataset_1_row IN --Cycle through rows of query below
            SELECT 
                column_name,
                table_name
            FROM information_schema.tables 
            NATURAL JOIN information_schema.columns 
            WHERE 
                table_schema='public'
                AND table_type='BASE TABLE'
                AND column_name ~ '^temp_'
            ORDER BY table_name,column_name
        LOOP

        RAISE NOTICE 'Table: %, Column: %',  dataset_1_row.table_name,dataset_1_row.column_name;
        --Create a dynamic update query to set to NULL the contents of the current 'temp_' column
        update_query :='UPDATE '||dataset_1_row.table_name||' SET '||dataset_1_row.column_name||'=NULL WHERE '||dataset_1_row.column_name||' IS NOT NULL;';
        RAISE LOG 'Query executed: %', update_query; --Put query def in log
        EXECUTE update_query; --Run the query
    END LOOP; --Next line of SELECT query above 

    RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```