# EXPLAIN ANALYZE shows no details for queries inside a plpgsql function

Tags: postgresql, optimization, functions, plpgsql, explain

I am using a PL/pgSQL function in PostgreSQL 9.3 with several complex queries inside:

```
create function f1()
  returns integer as
$$
declare

event tablename%ROWTYPE;
....
....

begin

FOR event IN
   SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE condition
LOOP
   EXECUTE 'SELECT f2(event.columnname)' INTO dummy_return;
END LOOP;

...

INSERT INTO ... FROM a LEFT JOIN b ... LEFT JOIN c WHERE ...

UPDATE T SET cl1 = M.cl1 FROM M WHERE M.pkcols = T.pkcols;

...

end
$$ language plpgsql;
```

If I ran `EXPLAIN ANALYZE f1()`, I only get the total time, but no details. Is there a way I can get detailed results for all queries in the function?

If queries in the function should not be optimized by Postgres, I would also ask for an explanation.

Comment: `auto_explain.log_nested_statements` might help. See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/auto-explain.html

Answer (score 37):

The correct syntax for the `EXPLAIN` call needs a `SELECT`. You can't just write the bare function name in SQL:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT f1();
```

#### Optimization

PL/pgSQL functions are **black boxes** to the query planner. Queries inside ***are*** optimized just like other queries, but ***separately*** and one by one like prepared statements, and the execution plan may be cached for the duration of the session. Details:

- [Function Performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8119/postgresql-stored-procedure-performance/8189#8189)

#### `EXPLAIN` function bodies

Like @Daniel already commented, you can use the additional module [**auto_explain**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auto-explain.html) to get more details (*lots* of details). Statements inside plpgsql functions are considered "nested statements". Be sure to set:

```
SET auto_explain.log_nested_statements = ON;
```

Detailed instructions:

- [Get query plan for SQL statement nested in a PL/pgSQL function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23355/get-a-query-plan-for-sql-statement-nested-in-a-pl-pgsql-function)

As an exception to the rule, simple SQL functions (not plpgsql) may be "inlined", i.e. the function code is inserted into the outer query and everything is executed like there wasn't a function to begin with. The query plan includes detailed information in such cases.

Comment: After enable the 'auto_explain' like below, load 'auto_explain';

set auto_explain.log_min_duration=0;

set auto_explain.log_nested_statements=ON;

SET auto_explain.log_analyze = true;  I'm getting below msg in log file, '2014-12-08 18:21:59 IST LOG:  could not receive data from client: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'  can anyone guide me wht is the actual issue....

Comment: Note: After running plpgsql function only i'm getting above msg in log file.