# SQL function with SELECT vs. PLPGSQL function with RETURN QUERY SELECT?

Tags: postgresql, functions, performance, plpgsql, postgresql-performance

Is there a difference between a plain SQL function doing a SQL query:

```
create function get_sports() returns setof sport as
$body$
    select * from sport;
$body$
language sql stable;
```

and PLPGSQL function returning that same SQL query:

```
create function get_sports() returns setof sport as
$body$
begin
    return query select * from sport;
end
$body$
language plpgsql stable;
```

with regards to performance? In which situation should which version be used?

And what if we pass arguments, does that change anything? Such as:

```
create function get_sports(status int) returns setof sport as
$body$
    select * from sport where status = $1;
$body$
language sql stable;

create function get_sports(status int) returns setof sport as
$body$
begin
    return query select * from sport where status = $1;
end
$body$
language plpgsql stable;
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are various subtle differences.

Simple SQL functions can be [inlined](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions) when nested in an outer query - provided they meet some preconditions. Not possible for a PL/pgSQL function.

All statements in the same SQL function are planned at once at call time, while PL/pgSQL functions treat nested SQL DML statements much like prepared statements - only planning each when executed the first time, and possibly saving the query plan for the duration of a session. This is a *major* difference that influences behavior and performance.

For example, you cannot create a (temporary) table and use it later in the same SQL function, because it would have to exist at call time for the later statements to be planned. You need PL/pgSQL for that.

Code branches in PL/pgSQL functions that are not reached and thus never planned or executed may harbor undetected bugs until finally executed. PL/pgSQL function are only tested superficially at creation time.

Also, an SQL function only returns the output of the *last* query. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html#XFUNC-SQL-FUNCTIONS-RETURNING-SET)

> When an SQL function is declared as returning `SETOF`***`sometype`***, the **function's final query** is executed to completion, and each row it outputs is returned as an element of the result set.

Bold emphasis mine. (You might use `UNION` (`ALL`) to combine multiple query results.)

`RETURN QUERY`, on the other hand, *appends* to the result and can be called *multiple times*. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING)

> `RETURN NEXT` and `RETURN QUERY` do not actually return from the function
> — **they simply append zero or more rows to the function's result set**.
> Execution then continues with the next statement in the PL/pgSQL
> function. As successive `RETURN NEXT` or `RETURN QUERY` commands are
> executed, the result set is built up. A final `RETURN`, which should
> have no argument, causes control to exit the function (or you can just
> let control reach the end of the function).

Related:

- [FUNCTION syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15731425/939860)

Passing **arguments** works pretty much the same for either PL. (There used to be more differences in *old* versions, like SQL functions couldn't refer to  parameter names. But that's history.)

There are other, more or less subtle differences. See:

- [Difference between language sql and language plpgsql in PostgreSQL functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24771561/939860)
- [Function Performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8119/function-performance/8189#8189)
- [EXPLAIN ANALYZE shows no details for queries inside a plpgsql function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/84414/explain-analyze-shows-no-details-for-queries-inside-a-plpgsql-function/84496#84496)
- [SQL injection in Postgres functions vs prepared queries](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/49699/sql-injection-in-postgres-functions-vs-prepared-queries/49718#49718)