# Is there a parser for Postgres' auto_explain to make it easier to read and understand?

Tags: postgresql, profiler, explain

We have a number of Postgres functions that each call a number of other Postgres functions. If you simply `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` a call like `SELECT parent_function()`, the output is minimal, since it doesn't dive into the calls the parent_function makes.
Thanks to answers like this ([Get query plan for SQL statement nested in a PL/pgSQL function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23355/get-a-query-plan-for-sql-statement-nested-in-a-pl-pgsql-function)), we discovered `auto_explain`.

So, we turned this stuff on:

```
auto_explain.log_min_duration = 0
auto_explain.log_analyze = true
auto_explain.log_verbose = true
auto_explain.log_timing = true
auto_explain.log_nested_statements = true
```

The good news is that it gave us what we were looking for: A way to see the timing of *every* nested statement called during a long-running function.
However, the output is *very* verbose, and it's hard to see the parent-child relationship I'm "used" to seeing in profilers:

```
some_big_function           1000ms
  --child_function1          800ms
    --child_child_function   600ms
  --child_function2          200ms
```

Is there a better way to view this log output? Ideally, it would group nested statements with their parents showing me, at a glance, where I should look.
We tried `pgbadger`, but it's not configured to parse `auto_explain` output, since `auto_explain` of this verbosity isn't usually running on production servers.

Are there other log parsers (or other techniques) to help profile functions?

Comment: For those that are reading this question, you'd likely want to know that pganalyze.com can help get timings without auto_explain. It uses pg_stat_statements to give per-statement (rather than per-function) timings of most things in your database. It's not aware of which statements are nested in which functions, but (since pg_stat_statements isn't either), but it's very helpful nonetheless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## SUGGESTION #1

If you are just looking to take an EXPLAIN plan and instantly present it, here is a SQL-Fiddle like site called [`explain.depesz.com`](http://explain.depesz.com/). Just copy-and-paste the explain and hit <kbd>Submit</kbd>.

## SUGGESTION #2

You could try pgAdminIII which comes with Graphical Explains

See the following links to how to use pgAdmin and other methods

- [PostgreSQL : Up and Running (Chapter ob pgAdmin)](https://books.google.com/books?id=ASjJBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA57&lpg=PA57&dq=pgadmin%20graphical%20explain&source=bl&ots=90V2cvVV1D&sig=vkMM-WbqFwdSHN5XlOzUrNPxxk0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=TWNnVZOZD4SusAXE84LwCw&ved=0CF4Q6AEwCQ#v=onepage&q=pgadmin%20graphical%20explain&f=false)
- [PostgreSQL Wiki's Using EXPLAIN](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Using_EXPLAIN)
- [READING PGADMIN GRAPHICAL EXPLAIN PLANS](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/27-Reading-PgAdmin-Graphical-Explain-Plans.html)
- [pgAdmin 1.4 online documentation](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.4/query.html)

Comment: This does not really help figuring out what the actual log line tries to tell - it is _really_ very convoluted.  Sometimes it contains several `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` outputs mixed with other information.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but I'm afraid that this doesn't work for PL/pgSQL functions. I can't just EXPLAIN a Postgres Function, since Postgres functions are optimization boundaries. The only recourse I appear to have is to turn on AUTO EXPLAIN, run our queries, and figure out where the time is going. However, the output from AUTO EXPLAIN in the logs is extremely verbose and disorganized, as @dezso pointed out.

Comment: Upon further review, the output from nested AUTO_EXPLAIN appears to come out in the correct order and be pasteable inside of explain.depesz.com. Thanks!