# PostgreSQL: Python UDF not shown in query plan obtained by EXPLAIN ANALYZE

Tags: postgresql, functions, explain, plpython

I have a question regarding the execution of a Python UDF. Let's suppose I have a UDF named testUDF(...) and I apply it to table "testtable". When I run the query `SELECT testUDF(...) from testtable`, I get the correct result (I omitted the params of the UDF on purpose).

However, when I want to check the query plan for this query, the UDF is not included in there. I used

```
 EXPLAIN ANALYZE 
 SELECT testUDF(...) 
 from testtable
```

and

```
 EXPLAIN 
 SELECT testUDF(...) 
 from testtable.
```

In both cases, the output only shows a seq. scan but the UDF is not mentioned anywhere. For more complex queries, I am interested in how to see at which position of the query plan the UDF is executed. How is this possible? Many thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I did follow the steps described here but the output was similar to the normal EXPLAIN. The UDF did not show up as part of the query plan.https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23355/postgres-query-plan-of-a-function-invocation-written-in-plpgsql

Comment: You need `explain (verbose)` (or `explain (analyze, verbose)` to see that the function is called. That would include e.g. `Output: testudf(...)` but you will never see the execution plan for statements _inside_ the function if that is what you are hoping for.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name That qualifies as an answer.